# Find_all not not finding all clases

Tags: python, web-scraping, findall

I wrote this code to find all firms links, but it finds only first two, then it stops. Any idea why and how can I change it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/branchen/rechtsanwalt/mannheim"
req = requests.get(url)
src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
all_firmas = soup.find_all("article", class_="mod mod-Treffer")
for i in all_firmas:
    i_2 = i.next_element.next_element
    print(i_2.get("href"))
print("Category done!")
```

Comment: Is there any chance that the site presents 2 by default, then loads any additional ones via javascript?

Comment: @JonSG Maybe, but I don't know how to check it. When I'm opening the page first 50 firmas appear, without scrolling down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your link, only two articles have the class "mod mod-Treffer". The other articles have the class "mod mod-Treffer mod-Treffer--kurz"

The following code also get the other articles using regex (`import re`).

```py
all_firmas = soup.find_all("article", class_=re.compile("mod mod-Treffer.+"))
```

Comment: This code works, but only for 3-50, first 2 are not included. I will create two iterations. Thx

Comment: replace .+ with .* to also get the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Using one class works, since all the articles have the mod-Treffer and mod is also applied to other elements you can just find with mod-Treffer like this

```
all_firmas = soup.find_all("article", class_="mod-Treffer")
```

To be more specific you can go with

```
all_firmas = soup.find("div", id="gs_treffer").find_all("article", class_="mod-Treffer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just use [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) with CSS Selector. It is similar to `find_all`.

```
all_firmas = soup.select("article.mod.mod-Treffer")
for i in all_firmas:
    print(i.a["href"])
```